# How to precompile Steal.js assets properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, asset-pipeline, stealjs

I have used [steal.js](http://stealjs.com/) as one of my assets. Previously I use it directly from public folder(i.e without pre-compile). Now I need to move its file to vendor assets so that it can be precompiled.

For this I used  gem `execjs` to precompile `.ejs` files and gem `less-rails` to precompile `.less` files.

After that I successfully precompile all the assets but unfortunately steal.js raise errors `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined` and system break up.

Can anyone help me fixing these issues ?

Answer (score 0):

You can mention specific file to get precompiled in application.rb as follow:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(
      steal.js
    )
```

Try adding this statement,It might help you

Comment: the asset `steal.js` has been pre-compiled but the precompiled steal.js does not work i.e it raise errors(as mentioned in question).

Comment: can you start changing the position of file. It might possible that this js has dependency on some other js